# How to set (limit) the number of cpu cores used by YOLO on darknet

Tags: deep-learning, object-detection, yolo, darknet

I am using [Darknet](https://pjreddie.com/) to train image data for object detection using YOLOv3 on a computer I share with others. Is there a way to limit the number of cores (CPUs) used by the network to avoid being ostracized by my colleagues? :)